# jQuery Update Hidden Field Based on Whether or Not Another Field's Value is In Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've done my best to debug this and research it on my own before posting this question.

I have an HTML form that has a field for zip code (element ID is #zip).

In most cases I would handle this with PHP, but this particular form is posting to an API and I don't have a chance to look at the variables before posting it.

I want to have several arrays of acceptable zip codes. I want to set a hidden field (#campaign) value to something based on whether or not it exists in one of the arrays, otherwise just mark it as out of area.

Please excuse the longform, I have to use **jQuery** instead of $ on this site.
script:

```
<script>
function checkValue(testTextbox){
 testTextbox.value = testTextbox.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
}
</script>
<script>
jQuery('#zip').change(function() {
var brzips = ['70815', '70895', '70835', '70814', '70827', '70816', '70819', '70879', '70809', '70822', '70806', '70812', '70836', '70896', '70898', '70805', '70884', '70808', '70818', '70892', '70817', '70811', '70802', '70727', '70874', '70810', '70873', '70891', '70826', '70831', '70833', '70837', '70739', '70821', '70804', '70825', '70801', '70894', '70823', '70803', '70726', '70820', '70893', '70807', '70813', '70714', '70786', '70704', '70767', '70706', '70769', '70776', '70719', '70780', '70770', '70785', '70710', '70728', '70791', '70765', '70734', '70721', '70738', '70737', '70764', '70707', '70718', '70777', '70733', '70754', '70729', '70774', '70736', '70773', '70740', '70788', '70778', '70725', '70752', '70453', '70772', '70749', '70744', '70346', '70449', '70730', '70783', '70762', '70757', '70748', '70711', '70760', '70722', '70462', '70755', '70341', '70723', '70782', '70393', '70391', '70789', '70086', '70784', '70756', '70443', '70466', '70732', '70792', '70441', '70775', '70763', '70403', '70743', '70451', '70052', '70401', '70339', '70071', '70402', '70761', '70404', '70390', '70759', '70421', '70076', '70422', '70051', '70454', '70456', '70090', '70084', '70436', '70049', '70747', '70750', '70069', '39631', '70787', '70446', '70455', '70372', '70068', '70465', '71353', '70552', '70715', '70712', '70442', '70444', '70521', '70301', '70310', '70302', '39669', '70371', '70079', '70582', '70517', '70523', '70057', '70519', '39645', '70514', '70753', '70512', '39638', '70078', '70563', '70447', '70544', '70437', '70380', '70522', '70395', '70352', '71358', '70342', '70047', '70381', '70540', '70577', '70538', '39657', '39632', '70392', '70080', '70340', '70356', '70562', '70064', '70039', '70359', '70087', '70070', '70030', '70560', '70569', '70065', '39633', '70433', '71369', '70450', '70031', '71345', '70518', '70457', '70434', '70062', '70435', '70097', '70063', '70501', '70507', '70471', '70394', '39652', '70470', '70502', '70509', '70593', '70520', '70505', '70033', '70598', '70003'];
var shrzips = ['71109', '71148', '71152', '71108', '71103', '71102', '71130', '71133', '71149', '71150', '71151', '71101', '71134', '71104', '71153', '71156', '71154', '71120', '71161', '71162', '71163', '71164', '71165', '71166', '71136', '71138', '71119', '71106', '71137', '71105', '71118', '71135', '71129', '71107', '71112', '71111', '71113', '71172', '71110', '71009', '71171', '71115', '71033', '71047', '71078', '71007', '71037', '71006', '75692', '71027', '75659', '71060', '71067', '75685', '71030', '71051', '71004', '71061', '71046', '71023', '75642', '75639', '75661', '71029', '71032', '75688', '71050', '71043', '71082', '71073', '71039', '75672', '71064', '71068', '71018', '71058', '71052', '71055', '75671', '71024', '75694', '75670', '71049', '71044', '71034', '71069', '75565', '71045', '71071', '75657', '75633', '75954', '75564', '75555', '75631', '71021', '71080', '71075', '75562', '71063', '71019', '71016', '71028', '71072', '75643', '75974', '75691', '75650', '71834', '71826', '75651', '75641', '71002', '75637', '71419', '71003', '71861', '75556', '75551', '71065', '71040', '75563', '71008', '75973', '71038', '71001', '75602', '75603', '75669', '75572', '75630', '75935', '71070', '71066', '75601', '75606', '75615', '75607', '71450', '75975', '75605', '71406', '71740', '71837', '75640', '75608', '75660', '71462', '71411', '75683', '75604', '75560', '71275', '75652', '75656'];
var dalzips = ['75172', '75241', '75134', '75146', '75217', '75253', '75303', '75216', '75277', '75339', '75336', '75180', '75232', '75125', '75159', '75227', '75376', '75215', '75210', '75224', '75115', '75203', '75123', '75237', '75222', '75262', '75263', '75264', '75265', '75154', '75315', '75149', '75301', '75181', '75233', '75226', '75223', '75208', '75185', '75187', '75242', '75250', '75371', '75270', '75313', '75202', '75246', '75395', '75267', '75266', '75283', '75284', '75285', '75312', '75320', '75373', '75392', '75260', '75326', '75397', '75201', '75137', '75116', '75204', '75359', '75398', '75211', '75228', '75357', '75236', '75150', '75393', '75214', '75207', '75138', '75342', '75394', '75219', '75182', '75106', '75218', '75212', '75206', '75390', '75152', '75205', '75221', '75372', '75104', '75249', '75275', '75360', '75235', '75114', '75382', '75358', '75209', '75247', '75356', '75049', '75043', '75238', '75225', '75126', '75231', '75047', '75041', '75355', '75165', '75220', '75017', '75367', '75354', '75060', '75389', '75051', '75243', '75230', '75052', '75157', '75374', '75042', '75053', '75168', '75046', '76065', '75251', '75088', '75030', '75229', '75061', '75040', '75050', '75054', '75378', '75015', '75240', '75045', '75244', '75062', '75380', '75081', '75085', '75039', '75016', '75014', '75089', '75119', '75254', '75167', '75083', '75120', '75044', '75234', '75379', '75032', '75391', '76096', '76018', '75158', '76014', '76007', '75038', '75080', '76010', '76002', '75381', '75248', '75001', '76006', '76155', '76011', '76004', '75048', '75082', '75006', '76019', '75160', '75063', '76005', '75252', '75142', '75370', '76015', '75368', '76063', '75087', '75011', '75101', '75261', '76001', '75086', '76013', '75287', '76012', '76094', '76084', '76040', '75075', '76039', '75074', '76017', '75094', '76003', '75098', '75007', '75026', '75019', '75093', '75132', '76016', '75099', '75023', '76021', '76022', '76120', '75010', '76041', '76064', '76060', '76061', '76095', '76099', '76051', '76053', '75166', '76623', '75024', '76124', '76112', '76034', '75105', '75189', '75025', '76054', '75067', '75002', '76118', '75155', '75161', '75118', '75056', '75013', '75057', '75029', '76119', '76181', '76180', '76009', '76651', '76105', '76140', '76103', '75027', '76092', '76182', '75173', '75143', '75028', '75121', '75034', '76117', '75035', '75022', '76148', '76111', '76028', '75077', '76248', '76104', '76115', '76134', '76097', '75070', '75164', '76150', '76110', '76197', '76191', '76193', '76195', '76113', '76166', '76101', '76102', '76198', '76137', '75407', '76626', '76199', '76196', '75033', '76122', '75069', '76161', '76163', '76670', '75065', '75102', '76130', '76129', '76162', '76050', '76190', '76244', '76262', '76133', '76164', '76147', '75068', '76123', '75474', '76106', '76036', '76109', '76185', '75147', '75110', '76107', '76059', '75151', '75135', '75071', '76131', '76136', '75153', '76132', '76641', '75169', '76177', '76114', '75442', '76226', '75078', '76210', '75156', '76031', '76055', '76666', '76058', '76127', '76116', '76121', '76628', '76208', '76179', '75454', '76636', '76205', '76126', '76135', '76052', '75109', '76227', '76650', '75144', '76108', '75458', '75124', '75163', '75402', '76679', '76204', '76206', '76033', '76202', '76203', '76247', '75404', '76209', '76201', '75009', '75117', '75103', '76207', '75403', '75097', '76631', '76093', '75401', '75424', '76645', '76044', '75409', '75453', '75472', '76660', '76192', '75148', '76639', '76071', '75485', '76259', '76681', '76098', '76020', '75127', '76258', '76627', '76008', '75423', '76078', '76249', '76648', '76035', '75495', '76676', '75058', '75422', '76621', '75848', '76266', '75859', '75140', '76271', '75452', '75751', '75490', '75440', '76023', '76692'];
var litzips = ['72209', '72219', '72214', '72204', '72206', '72205', '72103', '72215', '72216', '72225', '72255', '72202', '72164', '72201', '72211', '72203', '72260', '72207', '72217', '72227', '72221', '72295', '72210', '72053', '72114', '72212', '72002', '72115', '72119', '72222', '72183', '72089', '72022', '72065', '72190', '72118', '72116', '72223', '72231', '72199', '72117', '72011', '72180', '72124', '72113', '72120', '72142', '72158', '72018', '72019', '72015', '72135', '72132', '72078', '72076', '72099', '72083', '72106', '72079', '72122', '72182', '72046', '72167', '72150', '72086', '72023', '72168', '72016', '72129', '72087', '72037', '72035', '72032', '72034', '72033', '72128', '72173', '72152', '72007', '72070', '71602', '71612', '72176', '72104', '72126', '72181', '72045', '72107', '72105', '72024', '72072', '72057', '71909', '72125', '71611', '72047', '72127', '71613', '71601', '72012', '71603', '72175', '72058', '72084', '72111', '72004', '72110', '71901', '72001', '71910', '72066', '72073', '71903', '71902', '72136', '71725', '72102', '71914', '72157', '72052', '72064', '71913', '72061', '71941', '72156', '71956', '72025', '72160', '71659', '72039', '71949', '71942', '72068', '72137', '72027', '72060', '72170', '72131', '72063', '72041', '71665', '72143', '72823', '72040', '71748', '72145', '71968', '72149', '71929', '72013', '71964', '71644', '72082', '72857', '71678', '71998', '71999', '72178', '72858', '72017', '72085', '71923', '71652', '72853', '72030', '72003', '72134', '72133', '71667', '72028', '72080', '72545', '72543', '72026', '71742', '72829', '71763', '72081'];
if(jQuery.inArray(jQuery('#zip').val(), brzips) != -1) {
             jQuery("#campaign").val("CAMPAIGN ONE");
         }
         else if(jQuery.inArray(jQuery('#zip').val(), shrzips) != -1) {
             jQuery("#campaign").val("CAMPAIGN TWO");
         }
         else if(jQuery.inArray(jQuery('#zip').val(), dalzips) != -1) {
             jQuery("#campaign").val("CAMPAIGN THREE");
         }
         else if(jQuery.inArray(jQuery('#zip').val(), litzips) != -1) {
             jQuery("#campaign").val("CAMPAIGN FOUR");
         }
         else {
             jQuery("#campaign").val("OUT OF AREA");
         }
});
</script>
```

html:

```
 <form name="moreinfo_form" id="moreinfo_form" method="post" action="https://someurl.com">
    <input id="campaign" type="hidden" name="list" value="">
    <p><label for="first_name" class="required"><strong>*</strong>First Name<br></label>
    <input type="text" name="first_name" error="first_name_err"> </p>
    <p><label for="last_name" class="required"><strong>*</strong>Last Name<br></label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="last_name" error="last_name_err"> </p>
    <p><label for="number1" class="required"><strong>*</strong>Telephone<br></label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="number1" error="number1_err" onblur="checkValue(this)"> </p>
    <p><label for="street" class="required"><strong>*</strong>Street Address<br></label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="street" error="street_err"> </p>
    <p><label for="city" class="required"><strong>*</strong>City<br></label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="city" error="city_err"> </p>
    <p><label for="state" class="required"><strong>*</strong>State<br></label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="state" error="state_err"> </p>
    <p><label for="zip" class="required"><strong>* </strong>Zip Code<br></label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="zip" id="zip" error="zip_err"> </p>

    <p><input type="submit" value="Continue »"></p>
    <input type="hidden" name="required" value="first_name|First Name,last_name|Last Name,Address,number1|Telephone,street|Street Address,city|City,state|State,zip|Zip Code"/>
    </form>
```

I'm not receiving any errors in Firebug, but the Out of Area variable never populates so I am sure there's something wrong with either the trigger I'm using or just my horrible jQuery syntax.

Again, I appreciate anyone's help in solving  this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does appear to be working properly. Here is a working example: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wrxsti85/kbmdU/)

I used this basic markup for the test:

```
<label>Zipcode:</label><input id="zip" type="text" /><br />
<label>Result</label><input id="campaign" type="text" />
```

I used your exact jQuery script with no modifications as well.

Edit: Changed the event listener to the .blur() method from the .change() method upon OP's request.

Edit: Your script is never initializing. It needs to be wrapped in a ready function. Try wrapping your script in this:

```
jQuery(function(){

});
```

The more full code would look like this:

```
<script>
    jQuery(function(){
        jQuery('#zip').blur(function () {
            var brzips = ['70815', '70895', '70835'];
            var shrzips = ['71109', '71148', '71152'];
            var dalzips = ['75172', '75241', '75134'];
            var litzips = ['72209', '72219', '72214'];
            if (jQuery.inArray(jQuery('#zip').val(), brzips) != -1) {
                jQuery("#campaign").val("CAMPAIGN ONE");
            } else if (jQuery.inArray(jQuery('#zip').val(), shrzips) != -1) {
                jQuery("#campaign").val("CAMPAIGN TWO");
            } else if (jQuery.inArray(jQuery('#zip').val(), dalzips) != -1) {
                jQuery("#campaign").val("CAMPAIGN THREE");
            } else if (jQuery.inArray(jQuery('#zip').val(), litzips) != -1) {
                jQuery("#campaign").val("CAMPAIGN FOUR");
            } else {
                jQuery("#campaign").val("OUT OF AREA");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there a way to do it without pressing the enter key? Like a tab out into another field? Also, I tested the fiddle and everything gives me the else answer, out of area, even if it's in one of the zips in the array. Are my arrays built incorrectly?

Comment: Yes we can make it happen on tab using .blur(). Gimme a moment and I will update the fiddle.

Comment: @user3178191 Just updated the fiddle to work on tab.

Comment: You're right. So if the exact code is working in jFiddle, but not on the page, where would be the most likely place it is failing?

Comment: Is this located online for viewing, or local only?

Comment: Also, your script is not wrapped in a ready statement. I will put an edit in my answer providing more information.

Comment: That was it!!! Other than the obvious "Thank you very much", is there some other special way of showing appreciate on StackOverflow?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. A "thank you very much" suffices however :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the rest of your code looks like but what you have seems to be working for me. Maybe you could post more of your code or look through your code for conflicts? It it helps, all my page has is the inclusion of jquery and then the form with those two specific fields and campaign in type="hidden".